# Measurable Sets Definition

Tags: real-analysis

Definition: A set E is said to be measurable provided for any set $A$,
 $$\mathit{m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^c)}$$ 
(where $m^*$ is consider to be outer measure
We define the outer measure of $A, m^*(A)$, to be the infimum of all such sums, that is $m^*(A)= inf(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)\ |\ A \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty I_k)$)

Question: Prove that the definition of the measurable set does not change if we consider $A$ to be a Interval instead of Set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you asked - I wondered about this myself recently, never got around to thinking about it.

Suppose $E$ is "interval-measurable". Since $m^*$ is subadditive, to show that $E$ is "set-measurable" we need only show that if $A$ is any set then $$m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\setminus E)\le m^*(A).$$ Say $A\subset\bigcup I_j$ for some sequence of intervals $I_j$. Then $$A\cap E\subset\bigcup_j(I_j\cap E),\quad A\setminus E\subset\bigcup_j(I_j\setminus E).$$Again since $m^*$ is subadditive it follows that $$m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\setminus E)\le\sum_j(m^*(I_j\cap E)+m^*(I_j\setminus E))
=\sum_jm^*(I_j)=\sum_j|I_j|.$$Take the inf of the right side over all covers of $A$ by sequences of intervals.

Comment: Thanks David, Now that i see and understand the answer, i have to mention that in my original problem statement the "set" refers to set E not to the set A like i mentioned.

Comment: One more thing: by $|I_j|$ you mean length of the intervals $I_j$ or to be consistent with the way I define outer measure $|I_j| = l(I_j)$, therefore 

$$m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\setminus E)\le\sum_j(m^*(I_j\cap E)+m^*(I_j\setminus E))
=\sum_jm^*(I_j)=\sum_jl(I_j)= m^*(A)$$

Comment: Right. So revise the notation to suit. This is where you're supposed to click on that little arrow and that little check mark, by the way...

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time, i am not sure what you are saying by little check mark

Comment: Look at my answer. Just to the left of the first paragraph, in the margin, you see two arrows and a little green check mark. If you click on the up arrow you "upvote" my answer (if you click on the down arrow you "downvote" it, presumably not applicable here). If you click on the check mark you "accept" it, meaning that you feel it does in fact answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the green check mark